# Mysql Database Insert with Python via MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

This is super basic, but I cannot seem to get it to work correctly, most of the querying I've done in python has been with the `django orm`.

This time I'm just looking to do a simple insert of data with `python MySQLdb`, I currently have:

```
phone_number = toasted_tree.xpath('//b/text()')

try:
    #the query to execute.
    connector.execute("""INSERT INTO mydbtable(phone_number) VALUES(%s) """,(phone_number))
    conn.commit()
    print 'success!'
except:
    conn.rollback()
    print 'failure'
conn.close()
```

The issue is, it keeps hitting the `except` block. I've triple-checked my connection settings to mysql and did a fake query directly against mysql like: `INSERT INTO mydbtable(phone_number) VALUES(1112223333); and it works fine.`

Is my syntax above wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't tell what the problem is, because your except block is catching and swallowing all exceptions. Don't do that.

Remove the try/except and let Python report what the problem is. Then, if it's something you can deal with, catch that *specific* exception and add code to do so.